# Extract a column from a CSV file

Tags: java, csv, extract

How to extract a column from a CSV file?

I'm kind of new to Java. How do you extract a specific column from a csv file. For example if I have this data:

```
Name,Date, Gender 
Tom, 11/10/2013, Male
Sarah, 23/2/2013, Female
Mike, 2/03/2013,Male
```

How would I extract the first and third columns? I am able to read the whole CSV file but I want to extract specific columns from it.

Comment: Please search SO before posting the question, I believe there are bunch of answers available already. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169038/read-csv-file-column-by-column-java,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013169/how-to-read-data-from-a-specific-column-from-csv-file-using-jsp-java

Comment: Rightly said by sanbhat, a search would have saved your time and duplication here.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net).  It handles complex csv including quotes/commas in cell values.

If you are doing this by hand, you'd loop through the CSV like you do now to get each line.  Then you'd use string.split(",") to get an array so you could choose columns.  This won't work if you have commas in columns though.

Answer (score 0):

```
String text ="Name,Date, Gender";

for(String a : text.split(","))
{
   String row =a.trim();
}
```